# Give parent the same width as child

Tags: html, css

(Note: For compatibility reasons I may only use HTML and CSS for this.)

I have a `div` containing an `h4` tag. What ends up happening is my `h4` tag has a auto-defined width based on how much text is included. However when I include it under my `div` tag the `div` automatically uses `width:100%` instead of surrounding the tag like I want it to.  This becomes a problem because when I change the color of the `div` via `hover` I see a ton of extra unfilled space.

Here is one example of the issue I'm experiencing:

```
<a href='./HH.html'>
<div id='homenav'>
    <h4>
        HH
    </h4>
</div>
</a>
```

This is my current CSS:

```
h4{padding:0px;Margin:5px;}
#homenav
{
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
   background: #e8edff;
   color: #669;
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display:-webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-pack:left;
   -webkit-box-align:left;
   display:-moz-box;
   -moz-box-pack:left;
   -moz-box-align:left;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 2px;
   width:auto;  
}

#homenav:hover
{
   background:#D0DAFD;
   color:#333399;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add display: inline-block to the parent div and remove the width attribute.

Example:

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
    <h2>Text</h2>
</div>

CSS:
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5qPH9/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table`. See your example modified: http://jsfiddle.net/cArg7/1/

```
h4{padding:0px;Margin:5px;}
#homenav
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
background: #e8edff;
color: #669;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2px;
width:auto; 
display: table;
}

#homenav:hover
{
background:#D0DAFD;
color:#333399;
}
```

And simplify the html code, merge `<a>` and `<div>` tags:

```
<a href='./HH.html' id='homenav'>
    <h4>
        HH
    </h4>
</a>
```

Comment: Okay now another problem that has come up is that the link is still active in that space, the div size is corrected but now if I click where that space was before the link is still active there.

Comment: @Tyler, OK, then simplify the HTML code and merge the `<a>` and `<div>` tags. http://jsfiddle.net/cArg7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `display` of the parent div to `inline-block` will wrap the parent div to the width of the text. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qA93S/) as an example.